# Symfony2, create a fake UploadedFile for functional test

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have a REST api written in Symfony2 with an API call to upload a file.

This file can't be more than 40MB and must respect some format.

I would like to know how I can create a fake `UploadedFile`

according to [Symfony2 documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) , it seems possible to precise the mime type, size and name , and even a mysterious "test" parameters (which i first thought was to be put as `true` when one want to tell Symfony it's a fake one) but it does not work (it wants a valid file path)

So how does people do, as in my case I can't put a 50mo file in my repository just for the sake of one functional test.

Comment: What is 40mo, 50mo? You mean MB?

Comment: hmm yes sorry, mega octet.